# Is there another way to assign value for k

Tags: java

The code given below is to find the no of triplets that produce a sum `num` the method here takes two pointer method and finds `pairsum` to match with the sum I am now able to get almost all the outputs as i can but there are still some cases which i was not able to find. The platform i worked on produced some test cases where the time limit exceeds this is due to the line in the else part which I've marked removing that assignment `k = arr.length - 1` , changes the entire output cases to wrong what should i do

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution { 
    
    public static int pairsum(int arr[], int sum,int j){
        int count=0;
        int k = arr.length - 1;
            while(j<k)
            {
                if(arr[j] + arr[k] == sum){
                    if(arr[j] == arr[k]){
                        int n = k - j + 1;
                        count = count + (n * (n - 1)) / 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                    //System.out.println(arr[i] + " " + arr[j] + " " + arr[k]);
                    count++;
                    k--;
                    }
                }
                else if(arr[j] + arr[k] > sum){
                    k--;
                }
                else{
                    j++;
                    k = arr.length - 1;//occurence of error
                }
                
            }
        
        return count;

    }
    public static int tripletSum(int[] arr, int num) {
        if(arr.length == 0)
            return 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] != arr[0]){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == true && arr[0] * 3 == num){
            return (arr.length * (arr.length - 1) * (arr.length - 2)) / 6;
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++){
            
            int sum = num - arr[i];
             count+=pairsum(arr,sum,i+1);
        }
        return count;
            
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try out the following code (no guarantee) but rather tried to provide corrections to your logic.

Nice is the handling of repeated values like 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 11, 11, 13...
However they provide extra counts, when for 16 several solutions (5, 11) are allowed (binomial, factorial). I did not think but assumed a solution (5, 11) counts as 1. Then duplicates in the array could have been removed and only unique values are remaining, simplifying the algorithm. In fact this is a requirement one should check. Below I count the same values at j and at k, which you neglected, only when at both ends they give the same value.

```
public static int pairsum(int arr[], int sum,int j){
    int count=0;
    int k = arr.length - 1;
    while (j < k) {
        int nj = 1; // Same values at lower bound.
        while (j < k && str[j + nj] == str[j]) {
            ++nj;
        }
        int nk = 1; // Same values at upper bound.
        while (j < k && str[k - nj] == str[k]) {
            ++nk;
        }
        
        if (arr[j] + arr[k] == sum) {
            if (arr[j] == arr[k]) { // Or k - j + 1 == nj
                count++; // binom(k - j´+ 1, 2)! For 1 - 4: 12, 13, 14; 23, 24; 34
                j = k; // Or break
            } else {
                count++; // nj, nk
                j = k;
            }
        }
        else if (arr[j] + arr[k] > sum){
            k -= nk;
        }
        else {
            j += nj;
            //k = arr.length - 1;//occurence of error
        }           
    }
    return count;
}

/**
 * @return the number of triplets summing up to num.
 */
public static int tripletSum(int[] arr, int num) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
        int sum = num - arr[i];
        count += pairsum(arr, sum, i+1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

The largest error was setting k back to the end.

The heuristic optimization, adding special cases, is not needed.

The naming could be more meaningful; as does spacing.

---

***Improvements***

If you make an array of unique values, and their frequency in the original array,
that would make the logic easier, and potentially faster.

For a huge original array, making those 2 arrays can be improved slightly be reusing the original array, sorting it, counting the duplicates:

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
int previous = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int duplicates = 0;
if (arr.length != 0 && arr[0] == Integer.MAX_VALUE) { // Cannot happen.
    duplicates = -1;
}
for (int value : arr) {
    if (value == previous) {
        duplicates++;
    }
}
int n = arr.length - duplicates;
int[] occurrences = new int[n]; // Needed when counting non-unique combinations.
int[] uniqueValues = arr;
int previous = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int i = 0;
for (int value : arr) {
    if (value != previous) {
        arr[i] = value; // Or uniqueValues[i] = value;
        occurrences[i] = 1;
        i++;
    } else {
        occurrences[i]++;
    }
}
assert i == n;

int k = n - 1;
```

Using [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte%5B%5D,int,int,byte)) would make a considerable difference.

```
int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, ...);
if (pos < 0) { // Not found
    int insertPos = ~pos;
    k = insertPos - 1;
} else { // Found
    k = pos;
}
```

In `pairsum` you could try to find the next k for value `sum - arr[j]`.
when not found decrement the k from the insert position.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest another simplest algorithm running also with duplicates values and optional zero.
First, sort all data in ascending order.
then loop on A B C , and stop asap: A+A+A or A+B+B or A+B+C less than sum.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

//------------------ RUN SOME TEST ---------------------
class QuickStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] myData = new Integer[] { 11, 40, 1, 20, 19, 100, 30, 2, 0, 33, 17, 17, 12 };
        searchTriples(53, myData);
        searchTriples(129, myData);
        searchTriples(3, myData);
    }

    // ----------------- MAIN ALGO PREPARE ------------------
    public static void searchTriples(int sum, Integer[] data) {
        // first sort ascendant
        Arrays.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder());
        // let see question
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println(String.format("searching for %d within:", sum));
        for (int num : data) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        // let name A,B,C the triple to be tested as A+B+C
        // C can go up to last indice , others a bit less
        int maxC = data.length - 1;
        int maxB = maxC - 1;
        int maxA = maxB - 1;
        int posA, posB, posC;
        Integer valA, valB, valC, valAB, valABC;
        // ------------------- MAIN ALGO LOOPS ------------------------
        // start with A as first data
        posA = 0;
        while (posA <= maxA) {
            valA = data[posA];
            // as B,C are less than A can cut
            if (valA + valA + valA < sum)
                break;
            // now add B
            posB = posA + 1;
            while (posB <= maxB) {
                valB = data[posB];
                valAB = valA + valB;
                if (valAB + valB < sum)
                    break;
                // now add C
                posC = posB + 1;
                while (posC <= maxC) {
                    valC = data[posC];
                    valABC = valAB + valC;
                    if (valABC < sum)
                        break;
                    if (valABC == sum) {
                        System.out.println(String.format("found %d+%d+%d = %d  (at pos: %d %d %d)", valA, valB, valC,
                                sum, posA, posB, posC));
                    }
                    posC += 1;
                }
                posB += 1;
            }
            posA += 1;
        }
    }
}

----------------------------
searching for 53 within:
100 40 33 30 20 19 17 17 12 11 2 1 0 
found 40+12+1 = 53  (at pos: 1 8 11)
found 40+11+2 = 53  (at pos: 1 9 10)
found 33+20+0 = 53  (at pos: 2 4 12)
found 33+19+1 = 53  (at pos: 2 5 11)
found 30+12+11 = 53  (at pos: 3 8 9)
found 19+17+17 = 53  (at pos: 5 6 7)
----------------------------   
searching for 129 within:   
100 40 33 30 20 19 17 17 12 11 2 1 0    
found 100+17+12 = 129  (at pos: 0 6 8)   
found 100+17+12 = 129  (at pos: 0 7 8)   
----------------------------
searching for 3 within:
100 40 33 30 20 19 17 17 12 11 2 1 0 
found 2+1+0 = 3  (at pos: 10 11 12)
```

COMMENTS :
with a bit more work, i think this algo can be coded as recursive, allowing to any depth , double, triple, quads, etc.
For another day :)

HTH